# Null values for Integer/Decimal datatype in Phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix, bigdata

I am creating Phoenix table with few integer/decimal column has been defined as Null but when we are getting data with null values in these columns then these records are getting rejected out. Null value in the varchar , char & Date datatype are getting loaded as expected.

Field Defination are like this ;

ACTIVE_IND INTEGER

Can we not store Null value in the integer/decimal columns in the Phoenix ? If we can, then what change we need to make it our end.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible to have null integer values. What phoenix/hbase version are you using? I tried the code below using phoenix-4.10.0 and it works fine:

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sometable (
. . . . . . . . . . . . .>     A INTEGER NOT NULL, 
. . . . . . . . . . . . .>     B INTEGER, 
. . . . . . . . . . . . .>     C INTEGER, 
. . . . . . . . . . . . .>     CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (A)
. . . . . . . . . . . . .> );
No rows affected (1.305 seconds)

0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> UPSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1,null,1);
1 row affected (0.06 seconds)

0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost> select * from sometable;
+----+-------+----+
| A  |   B   | C  |
+----+-------+----+
| 1  | null  | 1  |
+----+-------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have been using 4.7.0. Version.